# How to populate a nested List Class using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Not even sure I knew how to give the correct title for this question...

I have a class:

~ in 1st DLL

```
namespace ServerEnd
{
    class A
    {
         string field1 {get; set;}
         List<B> Nested {get;set;}
    }

    class B
    {
         string field1 { get; set;}
    }
}
```

~in 2nd DLL

```
namespace ClientEnd
{
    class A
    {
         string field1 {get; set;}
         List<B> Nested {get;set;}
    }

    class B
    {
         string field1 { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Now if I want to populate the client objects with the server objects I would use this:

```
var test = new ServerEnd.A();
test.field1 = "a test";
test.Nested = new ServerEnd.A.B();
test.Nested.Add(new (){field1 = "hi1" } ;

var clientModel = from x in test 
    select new ClientEnd.A
        {
            field1 = x.field1,
            * what do i put here to transpose data from list object *                
         };
```

But how do I populate the List from Server to Client?

Hope this is clear?

thanks

Comment: This looks much like a serialize and deserialize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use linq to build the ClientEnd.B objects

```
   var clientModel = from x in test 
        select new ClientEnd.A
            {
                field1 = x.field1,
                Nested = x.Nested
                          .Select(a=>new ClientEnd.B{ field1=a.field1 }).ToList()                
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you could work with it the same as with a property.

```
Nested = x.Nested;
```

If you want to create a separate list you can just use `ToList()` so it will create another one:

```
Nested = x.Nested.ToList();
```

Comment: HI, I actually phrased my question wrong but your answer gave me a clue to fix it.  As you answered the question i asked I accept - thanks

Comment: the types `ServerSide.B` and `ClientSide.B` are not the same, they just have the same properties so don't think this would work